# Issues with using bootstrap with rem = 10px

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using `Bootstrap 4` in my project. I am also starting to use `rem` as length unit. I have set `rem = 10px`, just so that it's easy to convert `px` to `rem`, which I believe, is standard practice. But doing so makes all `Bootstrap` defaults unusable (i.e too small). This happens because Bootstrap has started using `rem` in place of `px`.
So if I set my `rem = 10px`, I end up manually styling each and every element, even buttons because all elements become too small.

As an example:

For `.lead`, `font-size` is 1.25`rem` = 12.5`px`. Which is too small text.

I am just wondering that developers who use `Bootstrap` in their project, do they use `rem` or `px` as length unit. If rem, is it `10px` or `16px`?

Edit: Adding a picture to make it more clear

[image]

I hope it's not a stupid question.

Comment: I use `em` occasionally since it scales headers relative to the viewport. With `px` it can make the header and paragraph text size disproportionate on different screen sizes.

Comment: Add an example of code in your css where this is the problem, a better answer may be provided when you have a use-case you are referring to.

Comment: @Jake Thanks for feedback. Added a picture.

Answer (score 3):

`px` is not a reliable unit across devices as DPI varies. That's why Bootstrap uses `rem`. This is not their first attempt to implement `rem` as general spacing unit but they gave up in the past due to lack of support in legacy browsers. It appears those are no longer an issue...

Bootstrap 3 used `font-size: 10px;` on `<html>`, in order to set `1rem = 10px`.

Bootstrap 4 uses `font-size: 16px;` on mobile devices and `font-size:14px` on larger or higher density devices.

See [this discussion](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19943) for a few more opinions.

Answer (score 0):

- **Only Bootstrap 4:** One, not so good solution coming to my mind is to create css variables and using it throughout, ditching `rem` altogether.

  `:root{
     --custom-rem: 10px;
  }`
- **SCSS with bootstrap 4**: If you are using SCSS, write a function which will take px as input and convert it to rem. This way you can get away with rem = 16px.

  `@function remy($pxsize) {
      @return ($pxsize/16)+rem;
  }`

  `.myclass{
      margin-right: remy(10);;
    }`

PS: I can't format the code for some reason.

Comment: This is kinda one (y)

Answer (score 0):

I think the real answer here is to have setted the base rem to 10 px in the html and then modify bootstrap var $font-size-base to be 1.6rem and all those issues are gone

Answer (score -1):

One of the drawbacks to using a prebuilt css library is that you have to stick to their conventions unless you're willing to rewrite portions of their codebase.

In this case, I believe bootstrap uses the standard 16px = 1rem, and, like you said, if you want to use a different base unit you will have to reassign all the default bootstrap values.

Comment: You are right about drawback. I just want to know how do developers get around it. Do they stop using rem with bootstrap? or they keep it 16px?

Comment: I'd say if you're set on using bootstrap, use 16px as your base unit.